# Strip HTML tags AND double quotes

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to clean my entries that look like

```
“If you think adventure is dangerous, try routine; it is lethal.” 
<p>Life isn't about finding yourself it's about creating yourself. </p>
```

I need to remove HTML tags and double quotes and single quotes if they are in the beginning or the end of the string.

There was a function, but I don't remember what it was or something like a class...

Comment: why do you need a regex, there this function called [`strip_tags`](https://php.net/strip_tags) for html tags

Comment: it will not do the whole job

Comment: @stribizhev: just a side-note on editing titles - the community tends to prefer sentence case, rather than title case here. It's been discussed on _Meta_, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything with `^[“"'‘]|[”"'’]$|^<[^>]*?>|<[^>]*?>$`

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE6sH0/2).